# Merge maps from a list of maps java8

Tags: java, java-8

Hello fellow developers, 
Need your expertise on below problem
I have a below incoming list of maps

```
Map<String, Object> m1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
m1.put("name", "alex");
m1.put("age", "40");
l1.add(m1);
m1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
m1.put("name", "alex");
m1.put("state", "Texas");
l1.add(m1);

m1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
m1.put("name", "alice");
m1.put("age", "35");
l1.add(m1);
m1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
m1.put("name", "alice");
m1.put("state", "Arizona");
l1.add(m1);

m1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
m1.put("name", "bob");
m1.put("age", "25");
l1.add(m1);
m1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
m1.put("name", "bob");
m1.put("state", "Utah");
l1.add(m1);
```

I want the output list of map as below using java 8 streams-

```
[{name="alex", age="40", state="Texas"}
{name="alice", age="35", state="Arizona"}
{name="bob", age="25", state="Utah"}]
```

Appreciate any help here.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `toMap()` collector with merge function.

```
l1.stream()
   .collect(Collectors.toMap(m -> m.get("name").toString(), Function.identity(),
               (map1, map2) -> { map1.putAll(map2); return map1;})
           )
   .values();
```

Indeed in this solution, we merge maps based on *name* key value. so if two maps have the same value for *name* key then they will merge. 
since *toMap()* collector's result is `Map<String,Map<String,Object>>` here and desire result is `Map<String,Object>` so we have called `values()`